# How to read a file directly from disk in Liferay?

Tags: file, liferay, portlet

I'd like to manage a bunch of report files directly on a file system directly for easier use, especially when updating or excanging them with newer versions. And to avoid this intransparent document library.

Now i want to read one of these Files directly in liferay to pass them to JasperReports in general (e.g. as a ByteStream). I coudln't find any way to do this or something that discribes any way to handly files.

How is this possible to achieve? 
Or do i completely mess around with my idea?

Comment: Handling files in Liferay is not different to handling files in any other Java application.

Comment: Liferay is a portlet container, it is very different from "any other Java application". Do not try to use java.io package directly.

Answer (score 0):

You basically can leverage the powers of the Spring framework, since Liferay makes use of Spring more or less directly.

You need to use some sort of "resource adapter" to open files, which you can do in many ways. It pretty much depends where you put files and how they get there (if provided from outside or generated by a Liferay portlet itself, or provided as deployed resource).

I can recommend searching for the following Spring class to be used:

```
org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource
```

Nevertheless you should think about storing these files in the database, as this is much safer after all (transaction safety, security, ...).

Comment: Why is it better to go around with Spring instead of using file.io directly?

Comment: The spring way is using the equivalent of a "resource adapter" concept known to enterprise applications. Thus it enables transaction handling and such when accessing non-transactional input/output. If you just use file.io directly, there is no guarantee that file handles and file read/writes are managed correctly. Think about transaction rollbacks, system exceptions and other things important to enterprise applications. Liferay does use these APIs correctly along 99% of the implementation.